# A funny integral on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

So the question is to find a family of functions, $(f_n)_n$, from $[0,1]$ to the complex plane such that there is pointwise convergence to some function $f$ but that the integral over $[0,1]$ of $f$ does not equal the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of the integral of $f_n$. I came up with the function $e^{i(2 \pi 
x^n)}$ as my family of functions. For any fixed value of $n$, the integral of this function over $[0,1]$ lies on the unit circle and there is pointwise convergence to the constant function, $1$. However, the integral limit seems impossible to compute, so is Cauchy's theorem sufficient to argue that the limit of our integral is $0$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Try $f_n(x)=n^2x(1-x^2)^n$ which is an example from Rudin's book.